# Too big data output caused python socket corrupt

Tags: python, sockets

My code as the following:

```
class TCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
   def handle(self):
      while True:
         self.data = self.rfile.read()
         output = parse(self.data)
         self.wfile.write(output+'\n')
```

The output data very big, about 5MB. It caused the following exception:

```
self.wfile.write(output+'\n')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Should I add some parameter in the function wfile.write().
Any ideas please, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading a very large amount of content when you say

```
self.data = self.rfile.read()
```

You load the entire thing you're reading into that variable. The entire thing. Thats the disadvantage with read(). To lessen the burden, consider making a for loop with readline() and parsing/writing it as you go. That way the amount your computer has to handle at any given point is significantly less.

```
for line in self.rfile.readline():
    output = parse(line)
    self.wfile.write(output+'\n')
```

Also, not sure why the while loop is there, as the code should do its job with one iteration of that while loop.

Comment: The input is a binary data, readLine() is not good for binary data. I think the problem still in self.wfile.write(output+'\n'), thanks!

Comment: Ahh guess I learned something! The only way I see around this is to split up the amount you write out at once. Not sure whats good/bad for binary data, but could you split up your output variable if its already parsed? Breaking it down into smaller chunks might solve the issue.